# Запрет закрытия балуна крестиком

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Использую макет балуна вот из этого [примера](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout)

Я реализовал функцию закрытия в собственной кнопке.
Можно ли как то теперь совсем убрать из балуна крестик закрытия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У балуна есть [опция `closeButton`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/?from=SO#Balloon__param-options), с помощью которой можно отключить крестик в балуне. Например, вот так:

```
myMap.balloon.open([51.85, 38.37], "Содержимое балуна", {
    // Опция: не показываем кнопку закрытия.
    closeButton: false
});
```